# Repeater access elements

Tags: qt, qml, repeater, qtquick2

I have the following `Repeater`:

```
Repeater{
    id: rainDropId
    model: 200

    delegate: Rectangle {

        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * windowId.width)
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * windowId.height)
        property int mLayer: Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1

        property double mYSpeed: -2.0 * mLayer

        width:5
        height:5
        color: "#3399FF"
        radius: width*0.5
    }
}
```

And I have a `Timer`.
I want to modify the positions of all elements from the `Repeater` according to their own properties. How can I access something like `rainDropId[index]` from the `Timer`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Repeater`'s [`itemAt()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#itemAt-method) method:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: windowId
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Repeater {
        id: rainDropId
        model: 200

        delegate: Rectangle {
            width:5
            height:5
            color: "#3399FF"
            radius: width*0.5
        }
    }

    Timer {
        running: true
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        triggeredOnStart: true
        onTriggered: {
            for (var i = 0; i < rainDropId.count; ++i) {
                rainDropId.itemAt(i).x = Math.floor(Math.random() * windowId.width);
                rainDropId.itemAt(i).y = Math.floor(Math.random() * windowId.height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might also consider using [Qt Quick Particles](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-particles-system-example.html) to create rain drops.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more declarative way to iterate the children, like `for(r in rainDropId.items) { r.x = ....; r.y = ... }`